# Titanium Mobile and Flash Media Server (FMS)

Tags: flash, streaming, titanium, titanium-mobile, flash-media-server

I need to connect my Titanium app to a stream video server (fms). Is possible to do this with Titanium Mobile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can stream your video.

1) First is directly streaming video in video player of device but i think fms is not going to supported by default video player.

2) you have to embed your html 5's video tag.

For titanium I don't think there is any other way to stream live. I am native and titanium developer both. For my live streaming app i preferred to go for native development.